# How run form of one project in another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a two C# project: A and B, in project A I put button in windows form.. My question,  How can makes that button in project A run a form from project B?? "I included code in below"

Project A button code (OCR_MainForm.cs)

```
namespace ContourAnalysisDemo
{
    public partial class OCR_MainForm : Form
    {
     .
     .
     .
       private void btAutoGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new OCR_Data_Creation(processor).ShowDialog();
        }
```

Form in Project B needs to run in A (BPNN.cs)

```
namespace backprop.ocr
{


    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
         .
         .
         .
         .
```

Comment: Form1 f1 = new Form1(); f1.ShowDialog();

Comment: where should I putting it???

Comment: where you want to open

Answer (score 1):

Being in separate projects doesn't matter as long as the type has sufficient visibility (e.g. public) and the assembly is available/referenced.

Example:

```cs
using backprop.ocr; // so Form1 is readily accessible

// Later on, inside namespace/class ..

private void btnShowOtherForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var f1 = new Form1();
     f1.ShowDialog();
}
```

For multiple projects in a solution you still need to "Add [Project] Reference" between the projects; for projects in different solutions you'll need to build the dependency assembly first, and then "Add Reference [to Assembly]".